# Gradle productFlavors not separate in Build variant list

Tags: android, gradle

After update gradle to version 3, I can not see flavors separately.

```
flavorDimensions "forteLocal", "forteProd"
    productFlavors {
        forteLocal {
            dimension "forteLocal"
            buildConfigField 'String' , 'API_URL', '\"http://210.19.134.14:8080/\"'
            buildConfigField 'String' , 'LOGIN', '\"zen\"'
            buildConfigField 'String' , 'PASS', '\"Jksdsd12!!\"'
        }
        forteProd {
            dimension "forteProd"
            buildConfigField 'String' , 'API_URL', '\"http://210.19.134.14:80802/\"'
            buildConfigField 'String' , 'LOGIN', '\"\"'
            buildConfigField 'String' , 'PASS', '\"\"'
        }
    }
```

After synk gradle, but I get this.

[image]

I expect something like this

```
ForteLocalDebug
ForteLocalRelease
ForteProdDebug
ForteProdRelease
```

What to do to show 4 items, not only 2 items, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use default flavourDimension, like this

```
flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {

        localtest {
            dimension "default"
            buildConfigField 'String', 'API_URL', '\"http://212.19.134.14:80802/\"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'LOGIN', '\"tom\"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'PASS', '\"Aass1212!!\"'
        }

        bankProd {
            dimension "default"
            buildConfigField 'String', 'API_URL', '\"http://212.19.134.14:80802/\"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'LOGIN', '\"\"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'PASS', '\"\"'
        }
}
```